# Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric in insert statement

Tags: sql-server, types

I am trying to insert inside test_Master_Product key values (int values) that, actually, are nvarchar(50) from temp#Master_Product. I have tried either with convert, parse and cast. No one of them is working. The reason why I used nvarchar(50) was because in this temp table there were real values, that then have been updated with their key values. Now, I need to convert these values in INT data type because, even if they are nvarchar(50) they are in reality numbers.

Thanks for the support

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[test_Master_Product]
           ([PNC_KEY]
           ,[MODEL_KEY]
           ,[GPH_PRODUCT_GROUP_KEY]
           ,[PREDECESSOR_KEY]
           ,[SUCCESSOR_KEY]
           ,[PRODUCED_FROM]
           ,[PRODUCED_UNTIL]
           ,[PACKAGE_HEIGHT]
           ,[PACKAGE_WIDTH]
           ,[PACKAGE_DEPTH]
           ,[SHIPPING_VOLUME]
           ,[ACTIVE]
           ,[SUPPLIER_ID]
           ,[PRODUCTION_BASE_MODEL_KEY]
           ,[PRODGROUP_KEY]
           ,[BRAND_KEY]
           ,[PS_STATUS_KEY]
           ,[INTRASTAT_CODE_KEY]
           ,[FUNCTION_KEY]
           ,[CLASS_KEY]
           ,[INSTALLATION_KEY]
           ,[TYPOLOGY_KEY]
           ,[PLATFROM_KEY]
           ,[MASTER_MODEL_KEY]
           ,[BASE_TEMPLATE_MODEL_KEY]
           ,[PROJECT_NAME_KEY]
           ,[INSERT_DATE]
           ,[UPDATE_DATE])


SELECT   
       [PNC_KEY]
      ,CAST([MODEL_KEY] AS int)
      ,CAST([GPH_PRODUCT_GROUP_KEY] AS int)
      ,CAST([PREDECESSOR_KEY] AS int)
      ,CAST([SUCCESSOR_KEY] AS int)
      ,[PRODUCED_FROM]
      ,[PRODUCED_UNTIL]
      ,[PACKAGE_HEIGHT]
      ,[PACKAGE_WIDTH]
      ,[PACKAGE_DEPTH]
      ,CAST([SHIPPING_VOLUME]AS decimal(9,6))
      ,CAST([ACTIVE] AS bit)
      ,CAST([SUPPLIER_ID] AS int)
      ,CAST([PRODUCTION_BASE_MODEL_KEY] AS int)  
      ,CAST([PRODGROUP_KEY] AS int)
      ,CAST([BRAND_KEY] AS int)
      ,CAST([PS_STATUS_KEY] AS int)
      ,CAST([INTRASTAT_CODE_KEY] AS int)
      ,CAST([FUNCTION_KEY] AS int)
      ,CAST([CLASS_KEY] AS int)
      ,CAST([INSTALLATION_KEY] AS int)  
      ,CAST([TYPOLOGY_KEY] AS int)    
      ,CAST([PLATFROM_KEY] AS int)   
      ,CAST([MASTER_MODEL_KEY] AS int)
      ,CAST([BASE_TEMPLATE_MODEL_KEY] AS int)   
      ,CAST([PROJECT_NAME_KEY] AS int)
      ,[INSERT_DATE]
      ,[UPDATE_DATE]

FROM [temp#Master_Product]
```

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 659
Arithmetic overflow error converting nvarchar to data type numeric.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, you have a value that is too large for one of your `numeric` columns. Looking at your `INSERT` statement you *imply* that all of your columns are a `int`, but it seems that at least one of them is a `numeric`. I would start by looking at those.

Comment: The conversion is necessary later in order to add later FKs constraints on test_Master_Product

Comment: It is clear the conversion is needed, but one of your values is > 2147483647 which is why you are getting that error message.

Comment: If it were a cast of the value being larger than `2147483647` then the error would be `The conversion of the nvarchar value '2147483648' overflowed an int column.` @SeanLange and would have the error number `248`. [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=195bc8cfc6bc84feff6f4430c02ad910)

Comment: @LeonardoReffosco I agree with the other two comments.  Brute force recommendation is to first check to see if anything has a string length > 9 and view those records.  Another idea is to use BIGINT first and then see what records are larger then 2147483647.  Also, if you're still getting the error, you can try converting all to a Numeric(19,9) and see if its a decimal conversion problem.

Comment: thank you @Larnu the problem was related with SHIPPING_VOLUME column. I fixed.

Comment: @Larnu I am going to get a fresh cup of coffee now. :D

Comment: I just got myself a new cup of tea myself. Come join me @SeanLange . ;)

Comment: @Larnu - haha omw